# How to connect to WSDL web service?

Tags: web-services, http, soap, wsdl

Here is the following WSDL web services xml structures:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. -->
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://dispproj/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://dispproj/" name="DipService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://dispproj/" schemaLocation="http://www.example.com:8888/OfficeSRV/DipPort?xsd=1" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getDisp">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getDisp" />
    </message>
    <message name="getDispResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getDispResponse" />
    </message>
    <message name="getActiveoffice">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getActiveoffice" />
    </message>
    <message name="getActiveofficeResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getActiveofficeResponse" />
    </message>
    <portType name="Dip">
        <operation name="getDisp">
            <input message="tns:getDisp" />
            <output message="tns:getDispResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="getActiveoffice">
            <input message="tns:getActiveoffice" />
            <output message="tns:getActiveofficeResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="DipPortBinding" type="tns:Dip">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/" style="document" />
        <operation name="getDisp">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getActiveoffice">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="DipService">
        <port name="DipPort" binding="tns:DipPortBinding">
            <soap12:address location="http://www.example.com:8888/OfficeSRV/DipPort" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

And here is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://dispproj/" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://dispproj/">
    <xs:element name="getActiveoffice" type="tns:getActiveoffice" />
    <xs:element name="getActiveofficeResponse" type="tns:getActiveofficeResponse" />
    <xs:element name="getDisp" type="tns:getDisp" />
    <xs:element name="getDispResponse" type="tns:getDispResponse" />
    <xs:complexType name="getDisp">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getDispResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="tns:disp" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="disp">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="disps" type="xs:anyType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getActiveoffice">
        <xs:sequence />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getActiveofficeResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="tns:activeOffices" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="activeOffices">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="offADDRESS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="offEMAIL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="offFAX" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="offLIECENE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="offMobile" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="offPHONE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="offid" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="offname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I am using Postman (which is http request/response client) for Chrome:

Request URL: http://www.example.com:8888/OfficeSRV/DipPort

Request Body (I learned this body after testing it with: http://tomi.vanek.sk/index.php?page=wsdl-viewer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://dispproj/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <mns1:getActiveoffice xmlns:mns1="http://dispproj/" />
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The online WSDL client successfully retrieves a result, but when I tried the url and body of the request with Postman I got the following issues:

> 415: Unsupported Media Type

Are there some HTTP request headers that I am missing with my requests?

Comment: Looks like you have no problem connecting. If the "online WSDL client" works, then use Fiddler or something to watch what it does on the network, then make the browser version do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of tries I figured out that I have to supply the following HTTP Request Header:

Content-Type -> Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8

I figured out that by using: SoapUI